# NSDictionary get objects by property value

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have `NSDictionary` which contains following type of objects.

```
OBJECT1 - isFree:NO
          Name: Papaya

OBJECT2 - isFree:YES
          Name: Apple

OBJECT3 - isFree:YES
          Name: Grapes
```

I can get object for the given `key` by using `objectForKey` as follows.

```
NSString* contentId = @"OBJECT3";
ACBContentType *object = [[[ACBLibrary sharedLibrary] contentsDictionary] objectForKey:contentId];
```

However I want to get all the objects which `isFree:YES` by reading object `isFree` property. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are not interested in the keys, but solely the objects, it is pretty simply:

```
NSDictionary *contentDictionary = …;
NSPredicate *freePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isFree == %@", @YES];
NSArray* freeContent = [[contentDictionary allValues] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:freePredicate];
```

Typed in Safari.

`-allValues` returns an array of all value objects. `-filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` reduces this to the items fulfilling the predicate.

Comment: There is no `[contentDictionary allObjects]`. Can we use `allValues` instead of `allObjects`.

Comment: Yes, This is really optimum solution and in my case `predicateWithFormat:@"isFree == %@", @"YES"`.